# UIScrollView animation isn't smooth enough on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I am developing an application for iPad.

In this, I am using two `UIScrollView Controllers`.

When a user scrolls the first `ScrollView`, the Second `ScrollView` also has to scroll programmatically.

Similarly, when a user scrolls the 2nd Scroll View then the first `ScrollView` needs to scroll.

How to handle these 2 scroll views in the same View?

I have tried this:

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; method of the UIScrollViewDelegate.
```

But the scrolling animation is not smooth enough.

Please suggest to me any other way do this.

My code is:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
          if(scrollView == sub )
          {
             if(sub.isDragging)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Sub");
                 float x = main.contentSize.width/sub.contentSize.width;
                 CGPoint offset  = CGPointMake((sub.contentOffset.x*x), sub.contentOffset.y);
                 [main setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
             }
          }
          else if(scrollView == main)   
          {
             if(main.isDragging)
             {
                 float x = main.contentSize.width/sub.contentSize.width;
                 CGPoint offset  = CGPointMake((main.contentOffset.x/x), main.contentOffset.y);
                 [sub setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
            }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

instead of setContentOffset. And set animated to YES it will be smoother!